# Connecting to servers in xchat?

Tags: irc, xchat

I'm trying to connect to irc.rizon.net from an Ubuntu laptop. I've never done IRC from a Linux machine before, but I didn't think it would be any different than normal. I don't have any firewalls on (that I'm aware of), and I *think* I've got the ident process running like I'm supposed to. But whenever I try to connect to any of the servers I've tried, I get the following message:

```
Looking up irc.rizon.net
Connecting to us.iso.rizon.net (64.150.180.13) port 6667...
Connected. Now logging in...
Please wait while we process your connection.
*** Looking up your hostname...
*** Checking Ident
*** Found your hostname
*** Got Ident response
Closing Link: pha-med00115.dhcp.unc.edu (Registration timed out)
Disconnected (Remote host closed socket).
Cycling to next server in Rizon...
Disconnected ().
Looking up irc.rizon.net
Connecting to us.iso.rizon.net (198.87.3.75) port 6667...
Connected. Now logging in...
Please wait while we process your connection.
*** Looking up your hostname...
*** Checking Ident
*** Found your hostname
*** Got Ident response
Closing Link: pha-med00115.dhcp.unc.edu (Registration timed out)
```

That process just repeats until I close Xchat.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Does the same happen for other IRC networks (Freenode, QuakeNet, etc)? Does it help if you enable SSL for the connections (be sure to change port to _6697_)?

Comment: @grawity I get the same issue when trying to connect to freenode or quakenet, but I tried efnet and it worked instantly. I turned on SSL for rizon and allowed invalid certificates and that also worked. But turning on SSL and specifying 6697 for quakenet just makes it stall at the connecting step. It fixed the immediate issue though, thanks!

Comment: Well, Quakenet doesn't _do_ SSL. But as long as it works with Rizon...